# List View in Android studio not showing anything

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, listview

I am making a project in Android Studio using Java.

In this i am taking String inputs from the user via a Dialog and then storing them in an String array.
Then using an Array Adapter i am trying to get the Strings in my List View.

I have used 2 .xml files. One is the activity_main.xml and the other is the subjects_screen.xml

I want to start my app from the Activity_main.xml layout so that is why in the on Create function i have written `setContentView(R.id.activity_main)` . But now when i change the screen and go to subjects_screen.xml which contains the ListView , the ListView is not visible.

But when i replace the line `setContentView(R.id.activity_main)` to `setContentView(R.id.subjects_screen)` the ListView is visible.

How to solve this problem?

subjects_screen.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TitleText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Subjects"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/backButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:text="BACK"
    android:onClick="backToMain"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/removeButton"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.517"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/addButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/removeButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:text="REMOVE"
    android:onClick="removeSubject"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:text="ADD"
    android:onClick="addSubject"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/backButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/subjectList"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TitleText" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And for the List View I am using

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> subjectAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,subjectName);
    subjectList.setAdapter(subjectAdapter);
```

I have checked that the String array subjectName is correct.

Comment: So you're trying to use one Activity and switch its layout file accordingly? If that's the case I would recommend against it as your Activity class will soon become a mess. Just use a new Activity to show the list

Comment: Yes i am using single Activity and switch between different xml layouts. I will try using a new activity . Till then please suggest a solution using one Activity method.